# CSS3 Flex: flex-grow + justify-content?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, flex-grow

Good day,

I have one question

Can i use at once **flex** and **justify-content** ?

i want that "flex-item(s)" have the full size container and simultaneously space between it

```
<ul class="flex-container space-between">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7yttrtm4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use a margin for the childs:

```
.flex-item {
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

to remove the space to the left and right of the container use first- and last-child selectors:

```
.flex-item:first-child{
    margin-left: 0;
}

.flex-item:last-child{
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/7yttrtm4/2/

**or** add negative margin to the container:

```
.flex-container {
    margin: 0 -10px;
}
```

see:  http://jsfiddle.net/7yttrtm4/4/

Comment: that's what I do not want to , can you apply the responsive? , I have added a minimum size to the items [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7yttrtm4/3/)

Comment: other way to do it is to add   `margin: 0 -10px;` on the container. but in order to not have a horizontal scrollbar here you need to add an adittional wrapper with `overflow: hidden;` [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7yttrtm4/4/)